# How do I restrict access to custom List forms in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list, sharepoint-security

I am working on a workflow in SharePoint 2010 that is attached to a custom list where items require approval. During the course of the item approval process through the workflow, multiple teams have to review the item and sign off on it. Each team has different items to fill in but need to see all of it.

My solution for needing to restrict view vs. edit on the form was to create custom forms for the list that corresponds to each group. Legal, for example, has a different form than Operations where some fields are available to edit by members of the Legal team. Likewise, the Operations team has its own fields that it can edit.

What I want to do now is to prevent a user from loading the custom form if he or she is not in the correct group.

At the moment, these custom forms have no code attached them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're able to deploy solutions on the server, maybe SharePoint Permission Extensions from codeplex could solve your requirements. You can set permissions for each colum of a list separatley.

http://sppex.codeplex.com/

Cheers
Michael